# I want to count rows and columns in JS

Tags: javascript

I want to use Table class as can be easily implemented in JavaScript as shown in the following code snippet. After having declared the object, we can instantiate it by using the new operator and use its properties and methods.But my code is not working. Please have a look.

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>:Functions as Variables:</title>
    
    <style>
    table {margin-bottom:15px;}
    
    td {padding:10px; text-align:center; border:1px solid #cecece;}
    </style>
    
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0">
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    </tr>
    
    </table>
    
    
    
    <script>
    function table(row,column) {
    this.row = row;
    this.column = column;
    getCountCell = function(){
    return this.rows * this.column;
    } 
    }
    
    var c = new table(3,5);
    
    var t = c.getCountCell();
    
    
    console.log(t);
    
    
    
    
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Typo: `row !== rows`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can try this code

```
(function(){
    var rows;
    var columns;

    this.table = function table(row,column) {
        this.rows = row;
        this.columns = column;
    }

    table.prototype.getCountCell = function() {
        return this.rows * this.columns;
    }
 })();

var c = new table(3,5);
var t = c.getCountCell();
console.log(t);
```

Here is the details about [JavaScript prototype constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor)

Answer (score 0):

**spelling mistakes** is a `row` not `rows` and apply `this` in front of `this.getCountCell`

```js
  function table(row,column) {
    this.row = row;
    this.column = column;
    this.getCountCell = function(){
    return this.row * this.column;
    } 
    }
    
    var c = new table(3,5);
    
    var t = c.getCountCell();
    
    
    console.log(t);
```

```css
table {margin-bottom:15px;}
    
    td {padding:10px; text-align:center; border:1px solid #cecece;}
```

```html
    
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0">
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    </tr>
    
    </table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot prasad.